# Recreating tables in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I deleted a table in management studio, using code first entity framework shouldn't it automatically create the table again. How can I get this table to come back? Is there something in the package manager console I can say? Thanks for any help.

Can I delete the whole database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't care about the data, deleting it is probably the easiest option.  It should be automatically recreated.

EF won't recreate tables that have been deleted, however it may show an error due to the database not matching the dbcontext.  Going forward, you could enable the drop and recreate initializer for it to always recreate the db if it doesn't match, or enable migration support and script all changes.

Comment: I wound up just recreating the table manually. Thought that would have been messy but it worked. Thx